# Liferay 6.2 polls results restrictions to Admin Users

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I m using Liferay 6.2. in Polls Display Portlet after question is answered the polls result is displayed for all users . can we restrict the polls results to only admin users.

i m aware that some minor customization is required in \html\portlet\polls_display\view.jsp file  at line 94 in this line <%@ include file="/html/portlet/polls/view_question_results.jspf" %>. but not sure how to achieve the expected results. so, can anybody please help me how to achieve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can directly check on `permissionChecker.isOmniadmin()`, if you have access to `permissionChecker` object. Otherwise, you can use `PortalUtil.isOmniadmin(long userId)` using `userId` from `User` object.

Comment: You can extract `User` object from `ThemeDisplay` or use `PortalUtil.getUser(HttpServletRequest request) / PortalUtil.getUser(PortletRequest portletRequest)` if you have any `request` object.

Answer (score 1):

With the below code, one can restrict the Polls results to admin users only:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= PollsQuestionPermission.contains(permissionChecker, question, ActionKeys.UPDATE) %>">
        <%@ include file="/html/portlet/polls/view_question_results.jspf"%>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <br />
        <div>
            <b><i>Thank You For Your Response</i></b>
        </div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: with the above code. we can restrict the polls results to only admin users. but can i know what are different types of ActionKeys in polls??

Comment: For `PollsQuestion`, you can have `ADD_VOTE, DELETE, PERMISSIONS, UPDATE & VIEW`. You can find all these action values in `/portal-impl/src/resource-actions/polls.xml`

Comment: Hello, my pleasure. Meanwhile, you are checking `UPDATE` permission over `PollsQuestion`, so any role who has this permission will be able to see the results.